# How are primary keys autoassigned in sqlite3?

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I'm writing a node application using an sqlite3 db. Does anyone know, if I do an insert of multiple records, are the primary IDs autoassigned in the order the statements are given?

That is, for table with columns

```
  `id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  `field1` INTEGER,
  `field2` INTEGER
```

I submit a statement like:

`INSERT INTO table (field1, field2) VALUES (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6);`

If in the callback **this.lastID** is 20. Can I assume the rows are (16, 1, 2), ... (20, 5, 6)?

I've experimented with this and found that the ID always seems to be assigned this way, but is it reliable?

What if I also know that **this.lastID** was 15 before the insert, so I know the IDs are [15, ..., 20]?

For extra credit, same question if I submit the inserts separately and run the queries asynchronously: can I rely on the IDs being assigned in the order the statements were passed?

Comment: The two different algorithms used to calculate the rowid are described here: https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html

Comment: Thank you, I missed that. It doesn't fully answer the question (it describes how the ID is chosen, but not whether the order of a sequence of statements is guaranteed), but it does suggest the obvious solution: assign the IDs myself rather than letting sqlite generate them.